# Visual Studio 2012: "Live Error List" - how to turn it off?

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-2012

While I edit C# code in Visual Studio 2012, the "Error List" window continually updates with a list of current syntax errors etc. I find this very distracting and would like to turn it off.

Does anyone know how to turn it off?

(I don't really know what this VS feature is properly called, so someone might already have answered it... Apologies if this is the case.)

Comment: I find this feature helpful as I can look into the errors before even building the code. I usually keep it unpinned. That takes care of the distraction part as it hides it from my sight.

Comment: Close the window.  Or drag it to a corner where the sun doesn't shine.

Comment: But I *do* want to see the error list after I've done a compile. It's even more annoying having to toggle the error list all the time. I just want it to work like VS2010. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually unpin it (with the pin icon in its top right corner), and call it up when I want to see it by moving the mouse onto its title. Once you compile your project, the window will automatically come up if there are any errors.

Answer (score 8):

You can try with based on :  `General and deselecting the "Always show Error List if build finishes with errors"`

Tools -->Options--> Projects and Solutions   --> General and deselecting the "Always show Error List if build finishes with errors".

Comment: Thanks for this, the error list is so irritating and wrong. Wrong? Yes, wait until you get a linking error (C++), the error list will not help you in anyway. The actual answer is in the output Window.